# Do kills from Runic Mines raise the kill counter?

Tags: achievements, titan-quest-anniversary-edition

Thinking about trying the "I have minions for that." achievement a.k.a "kill less than 100 enemies as recorded in the menu" by using Rune Mastery, and using Runic Mines for my traps.

A.k.a like how Rogues have Lay Trap.

Would that work? Especially because if it doesn't, then only Nature Mastery allows a 0 kill run, since all the other minion / trap masteries need more levels to access the useful skills than can be gotten by pacifist quests.

Answer (score 1):

And I just tested it with a new character.

Yes, kills from mines are still "your" kills, and so it seems only Nature Mastery allows "no kill" runs.